# jQuery getJSON and get value from button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm download data from JSON file and display button with value:

```
     function iterateOverPrzepisy(best) {
                $('#listaPrzepisow').html('');

                $.getJSON('przepisy.json', function(data) {

     for (var x in przepisyDost) {


     $('#listaPrzepisow').append(" <div data-role=\"collapsible\"><h2>" + przepisyDost[x].nazwa + "</h2>" +
                                "<ul data-role=\"listview\" data-theme=\"d\" data-divider-theme=\"d\">" +
                                "<li>" +
                                "<h3>Składniki: " + przepisyDost[x].skladniki + "</h3>" +
                                "<p class='ui-li-desc' style='white-space: pre-wrap; text-align: justify;'>" + przepisyDost[x].tresc + "</p>" +
                                "<button id='ulubioneBtn' value='" + przepisyDost[x].id + "'>Ulubione</button></li>" +
                                "</ul>" +
                                "</div>");
                        j++;
                    }

                })
}
```

When I click to `button` `#ulubioneBtn` I would like to get value from this button. So I add `done` to `getJSON`

```
 }).done(function(data){

                $('button#ulubioneBtn').click(function (event) {

                    console.log("Ulubione: ");
                    event.preventDefault();

                    var id = $("button#ulubioneBtn").val();
                    console.log("Value: " + id);

                    //dodajemy do ulubionych
                    localStorage.setItem("ulubione"+id, id);



                });
            });
```

But it's not working. When I click on button `Ulubione` I always get in `console log value = 0`

Comment: What is the value when log the following code: `$(event.target).val()`?

Comment: Value of the button, it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`przepisyDost` does not appear to be defined at

```
for (var x in przepisyDost) {
```

? Try

```
for (var x in data.przepisyDost) {
```

Duplicate `id`'s are appended to `document` at

```
"<button id='ulubioneBtn' value='" + przepisyDost[x].id 
+ "'>Ulubione</button></li>" +
```

within `for` loop. Try substituting `class` for `id` when appending `html` string to `document`

```
"<button class='ulubioneBtn' value='" + data.przepisyDost[x].id 
+ "'>Ulubione</button></li>" +
```

You could use event delegation to attach `click` event to `.ulubioneBtn` elements, outside of `.done()`

```
$("#listaPrzepisow").on("click", ".ulubioneBtn", function() {
  // do stuff
})
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be that you add multiple buttons with the same id. An id of a html element should be unique.

Comment: use class to select your button `$('.btn-class').click(function (event) { ...`

Answer (score 0):

I have created a dummy JSON and executed the same JS with a single change.
In onclick handler instead of getting button I am using $(event.target).

And it is working fine.

Please find the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/85sctcn9/

```
$('button#ulubioneBtn').click(function (event) {
  console.log("Ulubione: ");
  event.preventDefault();
  var id = $(event.target).val();
  console.log("Value: " + id);
  //dodajemy do ulubionych
  localStorage.setItem("ulubione"+id, id);
});
```

Seems like first object doesn't have any id value.
Please check JSON response returned from server.

Hope this helps you in solving.